# How to disable "Authentication Required" pop up?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, parallels

I created a Web Application Using `ASP.NET MVC 4`, and uploaded it on a commercial web server. My problem is when I click the Actionlink pointing to `~/Account/LogOn`, an "**Authentication Required**" pop up appears.

This is the beginning of my problem because I don't know what settings I changed or is there a setting that I was not able to setup ?

I have created 2 Web Applications before Using ASP.NET MVC 3 and uploaded it on the same commercial web server and it runs perfectly. no hitches what-so-ever.

By the way, the access they gave me to the server is not Remote Desktop Connection, its Parallels.

vipul.surana I was not able to post a picture since I have less than 10 points. So, if it is ok with you I will give you the website address. The website address is www.clktb.com then press login found on the upper right part.

nwdev as per request here is my web.config code I did not change anything here except removing connection string and removed some comments from the original webconfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
     <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"  />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What authentication mode are you using for your application? It must be set to Windows authentication. Also, allow anonymous authentication in IIS.

Comment: I am using Forms authentication as of the moment. I will try your advice and use windows authentication. I would really love to set the allow anonymous authentication in IIS but since our web hosting is just an affordable one, they only let us use parallels, is there anyway I can add it in my code instead?

Comment: post the web.config code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here is the removed code of my Account/LogOn.

Based on the words of Mr. Damien Joe I Quote "If the later, then there is definitely an issue with your current website project." I double checked the codes in the VIEW of LogOn since it is premade by ASP.NET MVC 4 and I found a piece of code that is not in MVC 3 LogOn

```
    <%--<p><%: Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") %> if you don't have an account. </p>
    <hr />
    <section class="social" id="socialLoginForm">
        <h2>Use another service to log in.</h2>
        <%: Html.Action("ExternalLoginsList", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }) %>
    </section>--%>
```

When I removed this piece of code from my View Everything worked perfectly. As in Perfectly. I lost 1 day with this piece of code right here. hopefully, in the future people will see this and know what to do.

Comment: thanks for your input Damien Joe really helped me pin point the error

Comment: you are welcomed. If you think my post was helpful, you may the arrow on left to upvote it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Your authentication mode is set to Forms. Do not change it to Windows unless necessary
>   (Windows is only used in a LAN based environment where users are maintained by an
>   Active Directory).

I would check the directory permissions on your web site folder. Go to your website folder & right click Properties->Security & check if Authenticated users are added to the users group.

Also, are you using a webservice?

**Edit**
This is most likely a permissions issue on your website folder.
Check this link for more info on IIS http://support.microsoft.com/?id=258063
and also this thread on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/385025/windows-authentication-kept-asking-for-username-password)

Comment: I'm not using webservices. I checked that all the authenticated users are added to the users group - and they are all added.

Comment: @RodrigoBusa Also check the similar permissions exist for your files contained in that folder.

Comment: this is very helpful. I read it and checked my local IIS and found that there is an anonymous authentication and disable 401 challenge. Sadly, I cannot go to the IIS where this website is hosted because they only gave me a PARALLELS control panel to work with.

Comment: @RodrigoBusa you can raise a support ticket on your hosting provider and see if it helps. Does this work the same way for all your websites or is it happening for this website only? If the later, then there is definitely an issue with your current website project.

Comment: the only thing I did different from the other 2 projects that ran smoothly was I upgraded from MVC 3 to MVC 4...

Comment: this is due to the changes you made. If there is an issue on the server, I am always happy to reload this website.
Please make sure you have everything backup and please advise once you are ready. However, I cannot guarantee that after the reload, the site will work. Based on my investigation, this is something to do on your code. 

I understand your code works fine on your local PC and this is simply because of the admin role you have on your own PC. On the server, we cannot offer you all the highest privileges and you may experience this issue if part of your websites require higher role

Comment: thats what the support team from my site said.